# Sequelize - Query milliseconds field to get all data in same date

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

In my table `test`, I store field `date` with millisecond value, such as `1620287520000`, which is `Thu May 06 2021 07:52:00` in UTC date and time

let's say I have some record below

```
[
  {
     id:1,
     date:1620287520000
  },  
  {
     id:2,
     date:xxxx
  },
]
```

I want to get all data whose `date` is `Thu May 06 2021`, regardless of the time.

How to do it in Sequelize/nodejs way?

test.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const test = sequelizeClient.define('test', {
    ...,
    date:{
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });
  return test;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequelize operators in your where options, for example:

```
// first call Op from sequelize package
const {Op} = require('sequelize')

// calling data which is less than Thu May 07 2021 and Thu May 06 2021 with lt (less than) and gte (greater than equal) operators
const data = await Test.findAll({where: {
  date: {
    [Op.lt]: 'Thu May 07 2021', // not sure whether this would be valid date, if not change it to javascript valid date
    [Op.gte]: 'Thu May 06 2021'
  }
}})
```